# Can git branches be different after a merge?

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, git-merge

I made some work with git and github but had unexpected results. After months of work on a branch i merged it back on the master but while on github compare tells me that the branches are identical the files actually aren't. This is driving me crazy so here's my question:

1. Branch B forks from branch A
2. work gets done and pushed on branch A (commits, merges, resets, ...)
3. work gets done and pushed on branch B (commits, merges, resets, ...)
4. merge B into A

After the merge both the branches are modified?
Is it possible that branch A and B files are not identical after step 4?
If yes, what actions has made them different?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a trick question? A now has A+B changes, while B only has B, right?

Comment: Not a trick question but I guess it's not a very smart one... if I merge B into A but then i want to keep working on B with also the commits A received from other commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git, a branch is actually just a reference to a single commit.  Two branches can refer to the same commit, which would make them the same, however in your case, they must be referring to the same commit.

Let's say this is the current state of the two branches after step 3 in your example. "A" and "B" are the commits which A and B are tagged against

```
A B
↑ ↑
o o
↑↗
o
↑
o
```

Each commit in this graph so far has a single parent.  Each time you create a new commit in a branch, a new commit is made as a child of the current commit and the branch is changed to refer to this new commit.

When you merge in git, you create a merge commit, which is a special commit with multiple parents, which has differing changes to each parent.

When you run `git merge`, this merge commit is created and only the branch you are currently checked out in will be moved forwards to refer to this new commit.  Here is what would happen when you run `git merge B` while you have branch `A` checked out (step 4 in your example):

```
A
↑↖
o B
↑ ↑
o o
↑↗
o
↑
o
```

As you can see here, branch `B` has not changed at all, while branch `A` is now referring to the new merge commit.

The state of your files in a merge commit could be anything, but running `git merge` normally would try to contain a combination of the changes from both branches since they diverged.

Answer (score 1):

When you merge B into A, that only modifies branch A. It applies any changes in B (since the fork) onto A. Branch B is left unchanged by the merge. That is the expected behavior.

Typically if you've done work on a personal "feature branch" and merged that into the master or shared branch, you can now delete the feature branch.